# datatables count row count based on column value and append it to column header

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

So as the title says I am trying to count the number of times a specific character appears on a specific column for example if m appears 30 times I want to return 30 and append it to that column header.
This is part of what I have

```
   function loadData()
    {
    var counter = 0;
    dataTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
     ...
     ...
    "sAjaxSource": "ReturnData",
    "columnDefs": [
                    {          
                        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                          if( data == 'm') {
                            counter++;
                          }
                         return data; 
                        // not sure how to return counter to the column header
                        },
                        "targets": [1]
                  }, 
           ]
        } );
       console.log(counter);
      }
```

For example my table would look like

```
 id  char(3)
---   ----
 1     m
 2     l
 3     y
 4     m
 5     m
```

UPDATE: if i console log i get 0

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: returning the count to the column header. I am not sure how do that..

Comment: I suggest You show two tables: the one You have and the one You want. It would be much easier to understand Your question.

Comment: I only want one table. The column title before the data is loaded is called char, but once is loaded i want to append the number of counts m appears on that column so  I would want something like char(3)

Comment: You should show them in Your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append `counter` to the column header in the `initComplete` handler. Here is an example, counting all instances of "Firefox" and adds the number to the column header :

```js
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{          
        render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if (data.indexOf('Firefox')>-1) counter++;
                    return data;
                },
                targets: 1        
    }],
    initComplete : function() {
        counter =' (Firefox : '+counter+')';
        var $th = $("#example thead th:nth-child(2)");
        $th.text($th.text()+counter);
    }     
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ae7t7w4k/**

Comment: that worked man. Thanks! Just one thing, and I know this is kind of a new question, is it possible to expand this to multiple columns without just writing columnDefs multiple times

Comment: @user3547086 You are welcome! `targets` can be type of array, eg `target : [0,1,2,3]` means it targets the columns 0,1,2,3, so in the code above you would count any occurence of "firefox" (or in your code "m") in all columns 0,1,2,3.

Comment: cool man, thanks again. One thing, My table headers have expand several columns as well as rows. Is there a way to target a very specific column header?

Comment: nvm, I figure it out :)